# Salary Negotiations between 2 offers

Tags: job-search, salary, job-offer, negotiation

I got a offer letter from a company A. I am in talk with other company B. I am optimistic about getting offer from B. B asked about A's salary offer and I told them. In the meantime, A increased their offer, knowing that I am awaiting response from other company.

Should I inform B about A's increased offer. ( I have not got any written offer from B yet)

Company B is my first preference and will join them, even if they pay little less. But ideally, I would like to get salary close to A.

(Time is not a factor with 'A')

Comment: If they matched the first number would you go with B?  If not then you should tell B the new offer from A.

Comment: Probably yes (with first number), but how to negotiate with B for higher number: after the written offer letter or before that ?

Comment: So even if you got an acceptable offer from B you would still negotiate for more and keep A waiting?   You could negotiate your way out of an offer.

Comment: How signifigant of an increase did A offer? 10%?

Answer (score 6):

> Should I inform B about A's increased offer?

**Yes.**

Since B specifically asked about A's offer, and since the offer has recently been increased, you should inform them of the current value of this offer *now*. Waiting until you get an offer from B may signal that you are just playing games.

Still, be prepared to make a decision about A's offer in a timely manner. You don't yet have an offer from B, you may never actually get one, and at some point A is going to get tired of waiting.

Comment: Thanks Joe... 'A' have given me sufficient time to decide. Also, should I tell B about increased offer now or should I wait for the written offer ?

Comment: Yep. Until B provides a formal offer, you're taking a risk that A's offer expires while you wait.

Comment: Actually time is not a factor. 'A' has given me enough time to think and expecting B's offer much earlier than that. Only dilemma is whether to tell 'B' now or later (as Chad reasoned).

Comment: If salary were the deciding factor I would completely agree with this.  The OP indicated he was willing to take less to go with company B.  For that reason I prefer the don't make waves approach.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I inform B about A's increased offer?

**No**

Company B asked what the offer you had received was.  You provided that information.  If you send them an updated offer now they may decide they do not want to get into a bidding war, and not make you an offer at all.  And since you would prefer Company B this should be avoided.

If they ask you if anything has changed this would be a good time to inform them of the new offer.  However, if you wait until you get the offer from B, decide if that is acceptable to you.  If it is not acceptable then you can let them know A increased the offer, that you would prefer to work with them if they can match, they may agree.  But if their offer is acceptable, I would not risk having the offer withdraw by trying to get them to counter.